# Update Alias Programmatically

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I have a large website with 240 urls that need to be updated.  I would like to do this programmatically to avoid making errors.  I created the following function which seems to work.  There seems to be a good bit of complexity here for what I am trying to accomplish.  Is there a simplier way to update the url of a node?

```
function alias_replace($path, $lang, $new_alias) {

  $path_alias_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('path_alias');

  $alias_objects = $path_alias_manager->loadByProperties([
    'path'     => $path,
    'langcode' => $lang
  ]);
  
  foreach($alias_objects as $alias_object) {
    $alias_object->delete();
  }

  $path_alias_manager->create([
    'path'     => $path,
    'alias'    => $new_alias,
    'langcode' => $lang
  ])->save();

}
```

Comment: Why not use Pathauto to bulk generate?

Comment: The urls follow the website structure for content that we authored.  Here is a sample url: /daily-devotions/genesis-1to11/in-the-beginning. The content has been translated into Spanish and Chinese.  Chinese urls are mostly English.  The Spanish urls are in Spanish without the accent marks.  I'm not sure there is a Pathauto solution.

Comment: You should be able to set a Pathauto pattern for each language. (in Drupal 8) If you also have the transliteration module, and the token module installed, I think you be able to use the Pathauto solution for the use case you described.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on Pathauto -- I will look into this further.  Is the code I included above the best way to update the url for a node without Pathauto?

Answer (score 3):

A slightly simpler way I found is that you don't need to delete and create the alias object as you can just update its object properties in place with `->save()` like this:

```php
function alias_replace($path, $lang, $new_alias) {

  $path_alias_manager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('path_alias');

  $alias_objects = $path_alias_manager->loadByProperties([
    'path'     => $path,
    'langcode' => $lang
  ]);
  
  foreach($alias_objects as $alias_object) {
    $alias_object->alias = $new_alias;
    $alias_object->save();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This actually works... yea!